# get an image height within object element

Tags: jquery, html, height

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script language='javascript'>
        window.onload = function () {
            alert($('#object1').height());
        }; 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <object id="object1" height="205" width="246">
        <img id="Img1" height="205" width="246" src="../images/google_ad_example.jpg" />
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

using jquery:

```
alert($('#object1').height());
```

I'm  getting 19 back! and not 205 Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `width`/`height` attributes. That's ancient and not standard anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/keXRf/3/ (using `attr`) **or** you can always set the css like here and use `.css` http://jsfiddle.net/LAp2c/

link: http://api.jquery.com/height/ :)

Note: since attributes `height=` is used in your case; you can use `attr` and that will give you desired output, but the link should help you to understand better.

```
$('#object1').attr("height")
```

**also** extra info: you can assign `.css("height", 205)` for consistancy across bwoser, there is a good discussion in the link I shared above.

further: The difference between `.css('height')` and `.height()` is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, `400`) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, `400px`). The `.height()` method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

screenshot 1: in osx safari

[image]

screenshot 2:

[image]

Comment: the both `alert`s in your code return `205`. where is the difference? this shows the difference better: http://jsfiddle.net/keXRf/13/

Comment: HIya @Raminson hiya Thanks at first but for edit; first it returns 18 and for second it return 205 adding screen shot: i am on osx, safari, have a nice one, cheerios!

Comment: He is using the same method but your answer doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Hiya bro, I'm on osx, FF and it returns only `205`. i'll check it out on Safari.

Comment: HIya @roronoazorro there is a slight difference I think better explanation is here http://api.jquery.com/height/ let me know how it goes, cheerios!

Comment: @roronoazorro it solves the problem, using `attr()` is the best way to find the height of it in a cross-browser manner.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be

```
$('#object1 img').height()
```